# Print string from crtp type being instanciated

Tags: c++, crtp, static-polymorphism

This a snippet from the real code, but the idea is that i want to print the service type in my log.
In this example i'm trying to print it, but i get an exception, and i don't know why.
I have other methods using compile-time polymorphism which are working fine.

```
template <typename servicetype> class Service {
public:
        std::string& service_type() { return static_cast<servicetype*>(this)->service_type_impl(); }

};

class ServiceType1 : public Service<ServiceType1> {
public:
    ServiceType1() :service_type_("Service Type 1") {}
    std::string& service_type_impl() { return service_type_; }
private:
    std::string&& service_type_;
}; 

class ServiceType2 : public Service<ServiceType2> {
public:
    ServiceType2() :service_type_("Service Type 2") {}
    std::string& service_type_impl() { return service_type_; }
private:
    std::string&& service_type_;
}; 

template <typename T>
class Server
{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << service_.service_type()<<std::endl;
    }

    Service<T> service_;
}; 

 
int main()
{

    Server<ServiceType1> service_type1;
    Server<ServiceType2> service_type2;

    service_type1.print();
    service_type2.print();

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that rvalue reference?

Comment: @YksisarvinenInitially i  am using an rvalue in the constructor, to avoid the string copy

Comment: If you're returning a static storage, why not just `std::string_view service_type_impl(){return "Service Type X";}` ? I presume `Service Type X` is known in compile time in your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never construct objects of your implementation classes *ServiceType1* and *ServiceType2*.

You construct only Server and Service class objects.

One of possible options would be:

```
template <typename servicetype> class Service {
public:
    std::string& service_type() { 
        servicetype* pimpl = new servicetype;
        return pimpl->service_type_impl(); 
    }
};
```

but it totally depends on what you want to achieve.

And you need to replace

```
std::string&& service_type_;
```

to

```
std::string service_type_;
```

in both your derived classes so that this variable could really make a copy of the passed string.

Comment: Good catch, that's why CRTP class should not have `public` constructors.

Comment: thanks @Damir Tenishev.  I checked the omther methods and realized that this servicetype classes don't have member variables. Only methods. That's why i didn't got the error earlier.